# How would I make a form element that selects an option by clicking?

Tags: css, forms, html, radio-button

I'd like to have a form element, such as a drop down box, or something of the sort, that displays all of the items at once, similar to a radio button, but without the circle next to it. For example, here is a quick picture I made of what I want

[image]

I already know how to make the divs and whatnot, I just need to know how to click it and it automatically turns yellow and is "selected". If it could be JS free, that would help a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use radiobuttons, but wrap them into label and hide input itself. Here's an [example at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Klaster_1/xTG6T/1/).

HTML:

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="item">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/140/140/abstract">
    <div>Some text</div>
</label>
```

CSS:

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div {
    background: cyan;
    line-height: 40px;
}
input[type=radio] {
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
}
input[type=radio]:checked ~ div {
    background: lime;
}
```

Also, you might want to consider targetted browsers **:checked** support. For example, IE8 and below do not support this selector natively.

Answer (score 2):

You're a little limited without using javascript or anything but you can try the `:target`  pseudo class. Take a look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rkCSX/